# Elasticsearch how to use a script(file) in an update

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I would like to update one given document; using a saved script

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/customer92/listbuilder/a10/_update' -d '
{
     "_script": {
      "script":"summarization"
       }
}'
```

I have a `summarization.groovy` in my config/scripts folder. I am getting the following error:

```
{
   "error":
       "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested:     
        GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[No such property: 
        summarization for class: Script6]]; ",
   "status":400
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Elasticsearch has changed a lot since this answer (from documentation). Please refer to up-to-date documentation instead e.g. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_indexed_scripts

i am pretty sure this question is no longer relevant, but in case someone is interested still here goes:

the "script" field in the json should be an actual script not the name of a script. in your case script_id would be correct, also the name of the language should be added unless the default has been changed.

`curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/customer92/listbuilder/a10/_update' -d '
{
  "script_id":"summarization",
  "lang": "groovy"
}'`

for more details see: [Indexed Scripts](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_indexed_scripts) and [Update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#docs-update)

Comment: I do not believe that user2089283 is using an indexed script but rather a script saved in config/scripts. That is a script that is accessible even with  script.disable_dynamic: true

Comment: Even then it would be script_id not script in the json (afaik without looking into the docs now)

Comment: As per https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/10007 the `script` field can also be name of a script in `config/scripts/`. If the issue is fixed then you'll be able to use `script_file`.